# Was Satou lying when he said that beheading robs an Ajin of his memories?

Tags: ajin-demi-human

Satou threatened Key with beheading, telling him that his memories would vanish with the new head growing, but we know it is a lie from the biker Ajin (he was beheaded in his bike accident and retained all of his memories).

Since Satou had his own head blown off "onscreen" (yeah, its manga) at pointblank dozens of times by the special forces, and his seemingly extensive knowledge of Ajin powers, the question is:

Does Satou know that an Ajin's memories are retained even when beheaded by the time he threatens Key?

Comment: There is a chapter fairly early on of a man on his motorcycle. he crashes and dies, thus finding out he's an Ajin. He sees his arm lopped off and takes it home to dispose of it, leaving the remains of the crash at the site. He goes about his life in paranoia, thinking someone will find out about him, and he's right- he gets captured because they show him his helmet, still containing his head inside. He grew a new head and didn't even know about it, thus he retained his memories.